# Force boolean value outside of JS function scope

Tags: javascript

I would like to run the if statement within my scroll event listener below only once. Right now I believe it is not working because the function runs every time there is a scroll action which resets scroll25 to false, therefore making the if statement true each time. Is it possible for me to force the boolean value of scroll25 to be true outside of this function's scope so that the scroll listener can continue to run and only have the if statement work once?

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollTracking);

function scrollTracking() {
  var scroll25 = false;

  // Get client heights, 100%, 25% and 50%
  var clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  var perc25 = clientHeight * .25;
  var perc50 = clientHeight * .50;
  console.log('25%: ' + perc25 + ', 50%: ' + perc50);

  // Log scroll position from top of document.
  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
  console.log(scrollTop);

  // If scroll is within the clientHeight range of 25% - 50%, log 
  // message once.
  if (scrollTop >= perc25 && scrollTop < perc50 && !scroll25) {
    console.log("25% Reached. Success.");
    scroll25 = true;
  }
 }
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyzBVY

Comment: How about [`document.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollTracking)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)?

Comment: This works, however my function above is in progress and I plan to have additional if statements that I need the listener to watch out for. (Such as a log for reaching the clientHeight 50 - 75% range). In that case, I wouldn't want to stop the listener all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just declare it outside of the function

something like

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollTracking);

var scroll25 = false;

function scrollTracking() {


  // Get client heights, 100%, 25% and 50%
  var clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  var perc25 = clientHeight * .25;
  var perc50 = clientHeight * .50;
  console.log('25%: ' + perc25 + ', 50%: ' + perc50);

  // Log scroll position from top of document.
  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
  console.log(scrollTop);

  // If scroll is within the clientHeight range of 25% - 50%, log 
  // message once.
  if (scrollTop >= perc25 && scrollTop < perc50 && !scroll25) {
    console.log("25% Reached. Success.");
    scroll25 = true;
  }
 }
```